# Get configured "Order Size" of strategy

Tags: pine-script

is it possible to get the configured "Order Size" of a strategy?
If so, how?

I would need it to do some DCA calculations.

Thank you already for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [strategy.position_size](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dposition_size)

> *Direction and size of the current market position.*
>   *If the value is > 0, the market position is long.*
>   *If the value is < 0, the market position is short.*
>   *The absolute value is the number of contracts/shares/lots/units in trade (position size).*

You can't get the `Order size` without having a position, but you could do something like this:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

var float posSize = na

if bar_index==0
    label.new(bar_index, high, "FirstBar")
    strategy.entry("Dummy entry", strategy.long, when=true)
if bar_index==1    
    posSize  := strategy.position_size
    strategy.cancel("Dummy entry", when=true)

plot(posSize)
```

Comment: And how would I get the value without an open trade?

Comment: You can't, but I've edited my answer to provide a work-around.